# XP in Win7 virtual PC Security considerations

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, security, microsoft-virtual-pc

I have a Windows 7 PC but occasionally have the need to run old software that won't run on Windows 7 but would run on XP.

I have XP installed inside Windows Virtual PC and inside that XP networking connections have been disabled. This means that consequently within the XP environment there is no internet access.

However, from within this environment I can still see my machines C: drive and all the other mapped network drives that the host machine is mapped to.

On the assumption that XP was clean and virus free last time it was used, which was before XP support ended, are there any security risks involved in running XP this way?

My host machine and the servers where the network drives are stored are all Windows 7 and all have up to date anti-virus software running.

Edit: In answer to comments

The networking is disabled from Inside the XP and in Windows Virtual PC.

I have no intention of ever running any software that isn't already installed on the Virtual PC and see no reason to ever connect the virtual XP to a USB device.

I have only a graphics package and Cad software that I will be using.

Comment: so you are saying that the VM can read/write to shared windows folders ? if so, that is a way to get malware to your VM. at what level is the network turned OFF? in the xp os, or at the VM "hardware" layer?

Comment: You can pare down or turn off the drive sharing under the Integration Features settings for the VM.

Comment: agree, in the VM setting, you could disable the network card (not give it a network card), and turn off the shared folder feature in VM. then you are getting close to a secure system. you could also "go back in time" and start VM from fresh copy (take snapshots and start those). but It might not be useful for you anymore :)

Comment: @user1201232 Are you saying since I need to share some data with host.  If I repartition the HDD on the to create a small new drive make that the only external drive visible to XP and have networking disabled in both XP and the VM I should be OK?

Comment: I did not realize you used Ms virtual Pc.. agree with below, use virtualbox or such... then use it to isolate like I said above :) but you are never 100% safe.. unless you turn it OFF. good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can recomend to use virtualbox or other virtualization software instaead if security is concern. Because that way the guest system is almost totally isolated from the host os. Even if is proven to be possible to escape from a virtual machine and there are [commercial tools](http://www.darkreading.com/risk/hacking-tool-lets-a-vm-break-out-and-attack-its-host/d/d-id/1131254?) for that is a very rare occasion that you will never probably encounter.

Comment: Windows Virtual PC is virtualization software isn't it?

Comment: Yes but the xp implementation that comes with Windows 7 isn't totally isolated.

Answer (score 1):

There are three attack vectors remaining.

- Your host system gets infected by malware infecting the XP system. It's theoretically possible, but nothing I've ever heard of.
- More serious is an attack via a connected USB device. If you use USB devices on your virtual machine, make sure to [disable autorun features](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/967715).
- The remaining attack could come from infected software/files you introduce yourself to the XP system. If you are in doubt about the source of the file, use [VirusTotal](http://virustotal.com/) to scan it thoroughly.